# main.dart not found since upgrade to Dart 1.9.1

Tags: dart

Since I upgraded to **Dart 1.9.1** whenever I try to run my `main.dart` by clicking in *Run in Dartium* or *Run as JavaScript* I get this error on the browsers console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/main.dart
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js
```

I tried running my own `bin/server.dart` so I didn't rely on the pub server to serve my static files. From this script, the directions to reach the *web* folder usually where `"../web"`, I had to change this to just `"web"` in order for this to work.

Was there a change I am not aware? Is this a bug?

**Edit**
I also get this message on Dartium

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer.

**Update**

The directory problem might be because of a change an update in Shelf or Redstone. I did a pub update as suggested and that might have changed the way the framework looked for folders.

Comment: Try to delete the `.pub` folder and  run `pub cache repair`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks but no luck.

Comment: The `--no-sandbox` warning is only to make you aware that you are using an unsafe browser (see http://dartbug.com/23078)

Comment: What kind of application is it (Angular.dart, Polymer)? Can you try to find out if the error goes away if you got back to the previous Dart version? You could try to delete the `~/.pub-cache` directory. Some problems can't be fixed by `pub cache repair`.

Comment: I deleted my `ÀppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache` folder (windows), which usually works when things like this happen. Also my `.pub` folder, but I still get the same error. I created a new *uberlysimplewebapp* and it worked alright.

Comment: Dis you also run `pub upgrade` when you updated Dart? You could try to use the previous `pubspec.lock` and run `pub get` to revert dependency version. You can also check if you have the most recent code_transformers package. I think to remember that there were a similar issue with older versions of this package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to run an application (server-side) as a website.
If you press the icon next to the run icon and in the dropdown menu click on "Manage launches" you can click the left of the icons (the server-icon) which allows you to run a CommandLine application.

If you select your dart script here (server.dart or main.dart) you'll be able to use it.

Comment: This error results from an http GET request to `main.dart` resource.